# How do I determine if user has a default Outlook 2013 profile

Tags: outlook

Our internal app (written in FoxPro) was designed to allow the user to email reports.  The app would use/launch Outlook by default ONLY if the user had a default profile already configured; otherwise, the app would use a custom built client.

In order to accomplish this, we looked at Registry settings to see if a default profile existed.  Here is the code (FoxPro):

```
IF oReg.IsKey('',[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles]);
AND oReg.OpenKey([Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles],HKEY_CURRENT_USER) == 0;
AND oReg.GetKeyValue('DefaultProfile',@lcProfile) == 0;
AND !EMPTY(lcProfile);
AND oReg.IsKey('',[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\]+lcProfile+[\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046]);
AND oReg.OpenKey([Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\]+lcProfile+[\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046],HKEY_CURRENT_USER) == 0;
AND oReg.GetKeyValue('001e023d',@lcProfileFav) == 0;
AND '.fav' $ LOWER(lcProfileFav)
```

I've determined that Office 2013 uses a different registry structure for storing its Outlook profiles.  However, the key that I've always looked for in the past to determine the default profile (001e023d) is no longer found in the \0a0d020000000000c000000000000046 registry entry.

Is there any way to ensure that the current user has an existing profile before attempting to launch Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any profiles at all. One of them will be the default one.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction.  IOW, if I use regedit and view the Profiles\Outlook folder, I have about 18 hex values.  Is there one value in particular that indicates the presence of a profile?

Comment: For Outlook 2010 and older, use HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles. For Outlook 2013 or newer, use HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Profiles where xx is the version of Outlook.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, Just curious if you could clarify that answer.  As my original post indicates, I'm aware of the registry paths, what I'm not certain of is how to determine (within those paths) if a default profile exists.  You can see from my code sample, that in previous versions of Windows, there were specific key values that one had to check.  Those same key values don't seem to exist in Windows 7 so I'm not sure what to look at.

Comment: Are you saying you do not see these keys in regedit.exe?

Comment: Think I got it figured out.  Thanks for your help.  In the Profile Key, there used to be a value called DefaultProfile.  That no longer seems to be available.  This used to tell me which profile the user had selected as their default.  I would then check a specific value within the key of the default profile to ensure the profile was indeed set up.  That value no longer seems to be available either.  However, I think I can just work with what I've got.  Thanks.

Comment: Again, if there is at least one profile, there will be a default profile. Do you really need to know what it is in your case?

Comment: No, the only reason I needed to know in the past was so that I could check the value of a key within the profile to ensure it had been completely set up.  We had a few issues where people had started to set up a profile but never completed it but the profile showed in the registry.  It would cause problems when you tried to use it.